# Why was 'Reproduce Impress.js sample presentation in Objective C' closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, closed-questions

I've updated the question based on Bill's suggestions. Is it now a better question?

[How to scale transition UILabel without using a lot of memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210770/how-to-scale-transition-uilabel-without-using-a-lot-of-memory)

---

I asked the question *Reproduce Impress.js sample presentation in Objective C*.

What I'm trying to do is take text and animate it like Impress.js does (rotation and pan mostly, 3D is too complicated), without using a ton of memory. I had attempted to do this myself, but I found that increasing the scale factor significantly increased the amount of memory used. I stated this in my question. My intention was to find a way of doing this without eating up a lot of memory. I needed something to get me started.

I didn't get any answers for a while, and I edited my post multiple times to improve it. There was a comment by David early on that indicated my question was worded too broadly, so I corrected it (I had originally asked "what is the best way", which wasn't necessary).

I felt that it shouldn't have been that complicated (plain text transitions)... but since I was stuck and my question wasn't getting enough attention, I put a bounty 500 bounty on it. I wanted a little bit of sample code to get me started.

Someone did help out, with more than I expected of which I am very thankful. I awarded the bounty.

Shortly after this comment my question was closed on the grounds of "not a real question"... because I put a bounty on it asking for a bit of sample code?

I asked for more clarification, and someone said the question was too broad... how so? There are other questions that ask about rendering large images on SO, and the answer ends up referring to sample code that uses a CATiledLayer. We're talking about doing almost the same thing with text.

If there is something wrong with the way the question was worded? Can anyone suggest ways of further improving the question?

Answer (score 7):

- What you wrote looks like a set of requirements.
- You haven't shown any code of your own at all, just linked to a project in another language that you want someone to translate/duplicate.
- It looks like you're asking for both a recommendation and for a solution to be created for you.  Neither one of those normally makes a good question, and putting them together is just confusing.

Comment: OK, so I linked to a visual representation, not code. I had mentioned that I had tried doing a transition while increasing the scale factor and it used a lot of memory. Can you suggest a better way to word this question? I can add a code snippet, but I didn't think that was required in this case.

Comment: @Luke Show the code that you tried and ask for help with that.

Comment: Updated. How does it look now?

Comment: @Luke Huge improvement! Other people already reopened it, so I cleaned up some of the now off-topic comments.

Comment: Thanks Bill! Your advice was very helpful and clear to understand. I wish the close voters could be that specific.

Comment: I wanted add a second bounty (+250) to the question to address the memory problems. But it will only allow me to set another +500... because of the previous bounty? Don't really have a lot of rep.

Comment: @Luke Yes, that's because of the previous bounty. For some reason you have to double your bounty amount (up to 500) each time you offer a new bounty on the same question.  Search for `Can I raise my bounty?` on http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/1288